# Restriction of direct sum of sheaves is the direct sum of the restriction

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}_i$ (where $i$ runs over an arbitrary indexing set) are sheaves on a topological space $X.$

If $U\subseteq X$ is open, then (providing direct sums exist in our category) we can form the sheaves:

1. $\mathcal{G}_1=(\bigoplus_i \mathcal{F}_i)|_U,$
2. $\mathcal{G}_2=\bigoplus_i (\mathcal{F}_i|_U).$

Surely these are canonically isomorphic? I'd be most grateful if someone could check my reasoning:

**Abstract nonsense proof**

Let $i:U\to X$ be the canonical inclusion map.

Then $\cdot\,|_U$ is the same as the inverse image functor $i^{-1}.$

Since the inverse image functor is left-adjoint (to direct image functor), it preserves all colimits.

Taking direct sum is a colimit and so we are done. Q.E.D.

Comment: Yes, this is all true.

Comment: @MooS Thank you. And the same argument works for $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on a ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ provided that I replace "$i^{-1}$" by "$i^*$" - right?